# Unable to create a second cheerio / jquery object in node

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to create a second jquery object after parsing the original object.
This is an abridged version of my code

```
let tPage = ""
const $ = cheerio.load(pageHTML)
const iPage = $('body')

iPage.find('*').each(function() {
   <!- doing stuff -->
   tPage += '<+++ some html code added to the tPage string +++>'
}

const $abc = cheerio.load(tPage)
console.log(typeof $abc)
```

I need tPage converting back into a jquery object because I need to do further work on it.
But the typeof $abc keeps saying it's a function and not an object. so I can't manipulate it using jQuery methods.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of messing around, I got round it using this:

```
let tPage = ""
const $ = cheerio.load(pageHTML)
const iPage = $('body')

iPage.find('*').each(function() {
   <!- doing stuff -->
   tPage += '<+++ some html code added to the tPage string +++>'
}

const abc = $(tPage)
```

And extracting the HTML at the end:

```
console.log($.html(abc))
```